# Json structure changes once I close the app

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, asyncstorage

I'm having a weird, issue, actually, I'm working with react-redux in a react-native app.
when the user logs in, everything goes smoothly in the user profile, but once I close the app and go back again, I'm getting a weird JSON format.

User reducer :

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export function userReducer(
  state = AsyncStorage.getItem('user') ? AsyncStorage.getItem('user') : null,

  action,
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN':
      return action.payload;
    case 'LOGOUT':
      return null;
    case 'VERIFY':
      return { ...state, verified: action.payload };
    case 'USER_LIST_RESET':
      return { users: [] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Login Form:

```
  const submitForm = async () => {
  if (isValidForm()) {
    try {
     const { data } = await axios.post(
    'https://c36a-196-235-44-112.eu.ngrok.io/login',
        {
          email,
          password,
        },
      );
      dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', payload: data });
      AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data));
      console.log('Logged In');
      navigation.navigate('home');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }
};
```

Getting the user in the userProfile :

```
 const { user } = useSelector(state => ({ ...state }));
 console.log(user)
```

The first Data I get once I login :

```
{"first_name": "John", "id": "63b0a010c015dd4b1f5fdb2c", "last_name": "Doe", "message": "Register Success ! please activate your email to start", "picture": "pic.png", "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYzYjBhMDEwYzAxNWRkNGIxZjVmZGIyYyIsImlhdCI6MTY3Mjk1MjU3NCwiZXhwIjoxNjczNTU3Mzc0fQ.XI9JnC4eeOQb5YJkNCC-Bqw4F9gpA1Xm6k_qJdkaXuw", "username": "JohnDoe", "verified": false}
```

The second data I get once I close and re open the app :

```
{"_A": null, "_x": 0, "_y": 1, "_z": "{\"id\":\"63b0a010c015dd4b1f5fdb2c\",\"username\":\"JohnDoe\",\"picture\":\"pic.png\",\"first_name\":\"John\",\"last_name\":\"Doe\",\"token\":\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYzYjBhMDEwYzAxNWRkNGIxZjVmZGIyYyIsImlhdCI6MTY3Mjk1MTY3NiwiZXhwIjoxNjczNTU2NDc2fQ.lVLg3pjfTFGt1K63v76sucinIUZJgOxSujSox12Xy0s\",\"verified\":false,\"message\":\"Register Success ! please activate your email to start\"}"}
```

I was trying to get the same data if I close the app, but I'm not, I'm actually getting another JSON form that is not compatible with the logic I'm working with.

Comment: Have you printed your second data using `JSON.parse()`

Comment: try JSON.parse(jsonValue)

Comment: AsyncStorage use with async await then it will work properly

Comment: @DenizKaradağ i get an error if use JSON.parse SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"

Comment: @NensiKardani Where should I use await? didn't get data using Async, no need for await while setting the data right?

Comment: @YakupMalikov I'm getting  SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"

Comment: You need to `await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')` before the redux store is created and pass it as initialState. It shouldn't be the default value for the state argument in your user reducer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AsyncStorage.getItem()` returns a Promise, it is an asynchronous function:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage#getitem

So when retrieving an item you will either need to use async/await syntax to wait for the promise to resolve before you can do something with the retrieved item, or you will need to specify a callback function when calling `AsyncStorage.getItem()` in which you do something with the retrieved item.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the same case, but I was using this same method on my reducer and realized later on that because `AsyncStorge.getItem()` is a promise, I need to put that in a asyncThunk instead of passing it inside the reducer itself. I am using the new recommended redux toolkit: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide

Something like this:

```
export const getStoredToken = createAsyncThunk('getStoredToken', async () => {
  const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken')
    .then((token) => token)
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  if (token) {
    return JSON.parse(token);
  }
  return token;
}); 



const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(getStoredToken.fulfilled, (state, action: any) => {
        if (action.payload) {
          state.token = action.payload;
        }
      })
      .addCase(getStoredToken.pending, (state) => {
      });
  },
});

authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

Then use that later on on your components:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getStoredToken } from 'your-path-here';

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const { token } = useSelector(({ auth }) => auth);
    
dispatch(getStoredToken());
    
console.log(token)
```